# Membership sign up issue on iPhone X

Tags: civimember

We recently upgraded to CiviCRM 5.3.2 and have run into a couple of problems since then.

The main issue is that member sign up is not working on iPhone X when members try to pay with a credit cart (checks appear to be working fine).  I have tested a couple of phones, and iPhone X appears to be the only one having this issue.

What happens is that they fill out the registration form, hit "confirm", and then the confirmation page is missing their first and last name.

Has anyone run into this issue?

We are using Drupal 7.61.

Comment: What browser is being used for testing?

Comment: The browser being used in Safari.

Comment: Are you trying this as a member or as admin. I sometimes get odd behaviour in Safari when I test stuff as admin.

Comment: As a member, we have had one member complain of not being able to sign up , and I tried signing up from as a member from the iPhone X and ran into the same issue.